# Embedding QT application in Eclipse/RCP framework

Tags: java, eclipse, qt, qt4

I'm trying to embed my working QT application in Eclipse RCP framework(might not sound wise but i need to do this). I'm using QT 4.5 (not yet explored what QTJambi is all about and has to offer)

I convert my existing application as a dll and load it through eclipse application. Things dont work as they should as the QTApplication loop sits listening for events, and there is a good mismatch of events. Certain UI objects dont get the events. If I comment my Qppliaction::exec(), then the behaviour in QT app changes.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to achieve??

Thanks

Comment: What has become of your attempt?

Comment: Oh well, this was long time back. We had multiple applications, few in Qt/C++ and most of them in Java. We wanted to package them in one bundle and have same consistent UI so we thought of the above approach. But there were serious performance issues and a good mismatch of events. We did not go with the above approach but replicated UI in Qt the way we had in Java.